# add scroll down by 1 if div > at "x.top" or "x.left"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, position

**Hello.. i'm try to understand how i can add scroll if my div is > or < to value.**

what i have done :

```
(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).click(function(){
        var x = $(".wrapper").position();
        window.scrollBy(1, 1);
       alert("Top position: " + x.top + " Left position: " + x.left);
    });
});
```

so when i click this work and scroll my page x=1 and y=1 and i see Position of my div it's good but...

Now i try apply each time ".wrapper" is > top:300px or left:-300px scroll my page by x or y value :

```
<script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
          var x = $(".wrapper").position();
          if ( x.top > 400 )  {
              window.scrollBy(1, 1);
          }
       });
 </script>
```

i know my syntax is not good.. if someone can help me thanks :)

Here link to example : http://jsfiddle.net/zWtkc/18/

still not working but i have find other way to fix my prob. Thnks

Comment: Your question is not clear. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: You have a problem with syntax. It's not just "not good", it's wrong. Look at the brackets in the second example. I'll edit for you.

Comment: Hi, i try to achieve a scroll down activate by my wrapper div. example : When my div is on top: 400px this scroll down by 40px something like that.

Comment: i use scrollBy for deplace my scrollbar. in the frist example when i click in the window all the content is scroll by 1px x and y.

Comment: Do you need the function to be executed at click or at page load?

Comment: At page load, click is just for example.

Comment: Try to change `$(document).ready(function(){ ...  });`  with `$(window).load(function(){ ...  });`

Comment: Not working, maybe use offset ? but if you know a action like when wrapper is scroll add scroll to general window it can be good.

Comment: Now I'm confused. Can you post a real working example?

Comment: Here link to example : http://jsfiddle.net/zWtkc/17/

Comment: Does the box move by itself or do you fire a function to make it move?

Comment: the box move when i scroll :) , I have find a other way to fix my prob and its work good. Thanks for you help guys.

Comment: @niavlys please post it as an answer and check it as correct

Answer (score 1):

```
$(window).bind('mousewheel', function(e) {
 var x = $("#wrapper").position();
    if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta / 120 > 0) {
        window.scroll(1, 0);
    } else {
        window.scroll(0, 1);
    }
});
```

this is my solution to fix & add scroll reveal to scrollpath.js have fun , thanks all